# jQuery datepicker swipe

Tags: jquery, datepicker, swipe-gesture

Is it possible to browse months in datepicker, using swipe?
For example in my iPhone, when I swiperight throw calendar it will show me next month.
Please help me it is very important.

I tried to do something like this, but it is not working at all.

```
checkIn.datepicker(
{ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    firstDay: 1,
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShow: function()
    {
        jQuery('#ui-datepicker-div').on('swiperight', function() 
        {
            alert('next month');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461547/jquery-mobile-datepicker-change-month-on-swipe

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible approaches is to use [TouchSwipe jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin).

After including this to your project you can simply trigger click event on a corresponding arrow button like this:

```
$('#ui-datepicker-div').swipe({
        swipeRight:function(){
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').find("[data-handler='prev']").click();
        },
        swipeLeft:function(){
            $('#ui-datepicker-div').find("[data-handler='next']").click();
        }
})
```